# What elements of the pentagon lattice $N_5$ do not satisfy the distributive law?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I heard that the "pentagon lattice" $N_5 = (\{0,a,b,c,1\},\le)$ is not distributive, where $\le$ is the reflexive transitive closure of $\{(0,a),(a,b),(b,1),(0,c),(c,1)\}$.  What elements of $N_5$ do not satisfy the distributive law $(x\vee y)\wedge z = (x\wedge z)\vee(y\wedge z)$ or $(x\wedge y)\vee z = (x\vee z)\wedge(y\vee z)?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$a\vee(b \wedge c)=a$, while $(a\vee b)\wedge(a\vee c)=b$

Comment: I've been looking for an example of $(x\vee y)\wedge z = (x\wedge z)\vee(y\wedge z)$ myself.  Could you show one?

Comment: We get from the duality principle $b\wedge(a\vee c) \ne (b\wedge c)\vee(a\wedge c)$.